# Rotation matrices between two points on a sphere

Tags: geometry

Given two points on a sphere centred on the origin, $(x_1, y_1, z_1)^T$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)^T$, how can you determine the rotation matrices between them?

Comment: Hint: First do the special case where $(x_1,y_1,z_1) = (1,0,0)$...

Comment: There is an infinite number of them, one for each axis that lies on their angle bisector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$\vec{u} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{v} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
and the two vectors have the same length, i.e.
$$\left\lVert\vec{u}\right\rVert = \left\lVert\vec{v}\right\rVert$$
(If they are not the same length, then you'd need to scale as well as rotate to transform one to the other. However, the approach below will work for $\left\lVert\vec{u}\right\rVert \ne \left\lVert\vec{v}\right\rVert$, in the sense that one vector will be rotated to match the direction of the other vector, but retain its original length.)

If you want to rotate one to the other, the axis unit vector $\hat{a}$ is perpendicular to both vectors, and the angle between the two vectors is $\varphi$:

$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{a} &= \vec{u} \times \vec{v} \\
\hat{a} &= \frac{\vec{a}}{\left\lVert\vec{a}\right\rVert} \\
\sin \varphi &= \frac{\left\rVert \vec{u} \times \vec{v}\right\rVert}{\left\lVert\vec{u}\right\rVert \, \left\lVert\vec{v}\right\rVert} = \frac{\left\rVert \vec{a} \right\rVert}{\left\lVert\vec{u}\right\rVert \, \left\lVert\vec{v}\right\rVert} \\
\cos \varphi &= \frac{\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}}{\left\lVert\vec{u}\right\lVert \; \left\lVert\vec{v}\right\rVert} \\
\end{aligned}$$

You can construct the rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ [from the unit axis vector $\hat{a}$, $\cos\varphi$, and $\sin\varphi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle).

Note that if $\mathbf{R}$ rotates $\vec{u}$ to $\vec{v}$, i.e.
$$\mathbf{R}\vec{u} = \vec{v}$$
the inverse is
$$\mathbf{R}^{-1} \vec{v} = \mathbf{R}^T \vec{v} = \vec{u}$$
because $\mathbf{R}$ is orthonormal, and its inverse is its transpose.

Comment: If you want _all_ rotation matrices, then you can multiply this matrix $\mathbf R$ from the right by any rotation matrix with $\vec u$ as axis, or equivalently multiply it from the left with any rotation matrix about $\vec v$. That will give you all rotation matrices which move $\vec u$ to $\vec v$.